# Hidden fields in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My models has some fields that are not to be presented in views (like Id field).

So, when I post the form, these fields return with "null" value, unless I insert then as hidden fields in form.

There are another away to update a model, using only the fields in form ?

My actual code:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Create(Profissao model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        using (var escopo = Db.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                if (model.Id == 0)
                    Db.Profissoes.Add(model);
                else
                    Db.Profissoes.Update(model);

                Db.SaveChanges();
                escopo.Commit();

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                escopo.Rollback();
            }
        }                
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Can you reconstruct them server-side? Re-retrieve from the db, keep them in session, ...?

Comment: you should make use of ViewModels, otherwise you will have to expose your DB entity structure right to the View - hidden fields, ViewData and other potentially dangerous structures. And you should use this ViewModel to map changes made by user to your DB entity.

Comment: There are ways to associate the data being sent from the client with the desired entity. The question is, why not rely on the `Id`? It's usually the easiest and safest bet...

Comment: And don't forget to encrypt decrypt id or keep it in guid format in order to prevent Id modified by client side

Comment: @raderick, this will be filling field by field?

Comment: @paulolarini yes, most likely. You can try using some mapping libraries for that, but I suggest manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Dto's (Data transfer objects) to handle this.

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Passord { get; set; }

    public  string Email { get; set; }
}


public class UserDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Passord { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public UserDto FromModel(User user)
    {
        Name = user.Name;
        Passord = user.Passord;
        Email = user.Email;
        return this;
    }

    public User UpdataModel(User user)
    {
        user.Name = Name;
        user.Email = Email;

        return user;
    }
}
```

then you can pass around the Dto object to your view and in your post.

your post controller should look somthing like

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Create(ProfissaoDto model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        using (var escopo = Db.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                if (model.Id == 0)
                    Db.Profissoes.Add(ProfissaoDto.UpdateModel(new Profissao()));
                else
var model = Db.Profissao.find(Model.id);

                    Db.Profissoes.Update(ProfissaoDto.UpdateModel(model));

                escopo.Commit();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                escopo.Rollback();
            }

        }                
    }
    return View(model);
}
```